# NA in List vs. Vector

Tags: r

Can someone explain why NA is evaluated as TRUE when it's inside a vector, but FALSE when it's an element in a list? See below.

Big thanks for any help.

```
> is.numeric(c(1, 2, NA)[3])
[1] TRUE
> is.numeric(list(1, 2, NA)[[3]]) 
[1] FALSE
> typeof(c(1, 2, NA)[3])
[1] "double"
typeof(list(1, 2, NA)[[3]]) 
[1] "logical"
```

Answer (score 6):

It is related to type coercion in the `vector` to `numeric` as `vector` can have only a single type whereas each `list` element can be of different type.  By default, the `NA` is `logical`.  According to `?NA`

> NA is a logical constant of length 1 which contains a missing value indicator. NA can be coerced to any other vector type except raw. There are also constants **NA_integer_, NA_real_, NA_complex_ and NA_character_** of the other atomic vector types which support missing values: all of these are reserved words in the R language.

If we want numeric `NA` in a `list`, use `NA_real_`

```
typeof(list(1, 2, NA_real_)[[3]])
[1] "double"
```

Comment: Ah, ok.  Of course, thanks, makes complete sense.  This came up when I was using a logical vector to subset. Meanaing that using `df[c(1, 2, NA)]` doesn't exclude the third column of the df, which seems surprising to me.  So I suppose the correct procedure for generating a logical vector to use for subsetting is to first eliminate the NA's from the source that's being used to generate the logical vector?  Obviously I'm new to r, so the help is much appreciated

Comment: @oneyellowlion you may need `df[na.omit(c(1, 2, NA))]` if there are NA elements. The way in which missing values act is a bit different in subsettting than you expected.   Or just do `df[c(1, 2)]` to subset the 1st and 2nd columns.  the integer index is a position index

Comment: @oneyellowlion According to `?Extract` `NA- When extracting, a numerical, logical or character NA index picks an unknown element and so returns NA in the corresponding element of a logical, integer, numeric, complex or character result, and NULL for a list.`